# Center a Div Left Justified Text

Tags: html, css

I have some header text that is large font, two to four lines.  It is left justified, but I also want it centered horizontally and vertically.  The problem is that it wraps and leaves some blank space at the end of the div (which is set at a width of 600px).  So I want it to be centered horizontally, based not on 600px, but the width of the longest line.  Is there a way to make the div width the length of the longest line of text?

Comment: Add some code snippet to illustrate what have you tried so far.

Comment: Judging by the description I believe the answer is no. That's not the way line boxes work. However without a demo it's hard to comment further.

Comment: Entering _"center div in page"_ in the _Search Q&A_ box at the upper-right of this page gave me fourteen _thousand_ results for questions about this topic on stackoverflow. Maybe one of those will have an answer that will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's what you want?

```css
#container {
  background:gold;
  width:600px;
  font-size:2em;
  display:inline-block;
  }

#title {
  width:400px;
  margin-right:100px;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  font-weight:600;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  
<div id=container>
<p id=title>Here it comes a long sentence that takes about 2 lines.</p>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block`. Inline-block elements can have a width, but if none is specified, they take the width of their content.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `display: inline-block;` and `margin: 0px auto 0px auto;` to the element you want to centre; I am assuming that you want to centre a div of a varying width, so this code should work.